# Determine the values of k for which these planes are perpendicular

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> Plane 1 = $(1 + 4s + kt, 2 + 2s + t, 7 + 2t)$
>
> Plane 2 = $[4,1,-1] + s[1,0,5] + t[0,-3,3]$
>
> Determine the values of k for which these planes are perpendicular

When these planes are perpendicular their normal vectors are also perpendicular $$[(4,2,0) \times (k,1,2) ] \cdot [(1,0,5) \times (0,-3,3)] = 0$$
$$(4,-8,4-2k) \cdot (15,-3,-3) = 0$$

Solving for $k$ I get $k = -12$ but the back of the book says $k = \frac{31}{3}$

Comment: Looks like all your calculations are correct, are you sure you have the right planes?

Comment: I have done the calculation too & cannot see any problem with your solution ... maybe its a typo ?

Comment: The planes are the same from the question, the book's answer might have made an calculation error.